# Why the model size is in huge different between different optimizer?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

With TensorFlow, my model size(model.ckpt.data) is 88M when optimizer is `tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer`, but it turned to 220M when the optimizer changed to `tf.train.AdamOptimizer`.

Why is there so huge a difference?

Answer (score 2):

ADAM adds two running means (for gradient and square of gradient) as additional non-trainable parameters for each trainable parameter, meaning it increases the number of total parameters to three times. These non-trainable parameters are also saved as they are required to restart the learning process. That's why the model checkpoint is bigger.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The non-trainable parameters are saved only to restart the learning process according to your answer. I want to know more that whether I can choose to **not** save the two non-trainable parameters to make the model file smaller if I don't need to restart training? If the answer is yes, could you please give me some example codes or relative APIs? Thanks!